# How to Schedule Async Coroutine Functions with APScheduler?

Tags: python, python-asyncio, apscheduler

I am developing a service in Python to send automated emails and am facing challenges with scheduling asynchronous coroutine functions using **APScheduler**. The service is built with **FastAPI** to handle user inputs and **aiomysql** for asynchronous database operations. My goal is to schedule email sending tasks that involve asynchronous database calls.

Here's the setup for my APScheduler within the application:

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.asyncio import AsyncIOScheduler
from apscheduler.jobstores.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemyJobStore
from apscheduler.executors.pool import ThreadPoolExecutor

class APScheduler:

    jobstores = {
        'default': SQLAlchemyJobStore(url='mysql+pymysql://USER:PASSWORD@HOST/DATABASE')
    }

    executors = {
        'default': ThreadPoolExecutor(5)
    }

    def __init__(self):
        self._scheduler = AsyncIOScheduler(jobstores=self.jobstores, executors=self.executors)
        self._logger = create_logger("Scheduler")
        self.exchange_state = ExchangeStateMachine()

    def schedule_email(self, schedule_time, bot, contact, subject, email_body, campaign_id, thread_id=None, reply_id=None, attachments=[]):
        self._scheduler.add_job(
            self.exchange_state.send_email, 'date', run_date=schedule_time,
            kwargs={'bot': bot, 'contact': contact, 'subject': subject, 'email_body': email_body, 'campaign_id': campaign_id, 'thread_id': thread_id, 'reply_id': reply_id, 'attachments': attachments},
            id=f"send-email-{bot.id}-{contact.id}-{campaign_id}",
            replace_existing=True
        )
        self._logger.info(f"Email scheduled: To {contact.email} from {bot.email} at {schedule_time}.")
```

The `ExchangeStateMachine.send_email` method, intended for scheduling, includes several asynchronous database operations:

```
class ExchangeStateMachine:

    async def send_email(self, bot, contact, subject, email_body, campaign_id, thread_id=None, reply_id=None, attachments=[]):
        # Asynchronous operations here
        self._logger.info("Send email callback invoked.")
```

However, attempting to schedule this coroutine results in a traceback indicating that the coroutine was never awaited:

```
RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'ExchangeStateMachine.send_email' was never awaited
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

I tried capturing the asyncio event loop at the start of the FastAPI application and passing it to the APScheduler or directly to the job function, using `asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe` to schedule the coroutine.

Despite these efforts, I continue to encounter the "coroutine was never awaited" warning, and I'm unsure how to proceed to correctly schedule and execute asynchronous coroutine functions with APScheduler.

How can I properly schedule and execute async coroutine functions with APScheduler?

Comment: Generally, in `asyncio` and `aspscheduler` context you shouldn't use `ThreadPoolExecutor`. Instead, you can use the `AsyncIOExecutor`

Comment: Thanks @BenyaminJafari, that was indeed the problem! I removed the `ThreadPoolExecutor` and replaced it with an `AsyncIOExecutor`

Comment: @BenyaminJafari do you know if I can combine the `AsyncIOExecutor ` with a `ProcessPoolExecutor`?

Comment: Yes, I think so. To combine `AsyncIOExecutor` and `ProcessPoolExecutor`, configure the scheduler with both executors and specify the appropriate one when scheduling jobs